# Meteor CollectionFS, condition for each store?

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to add a condition for each FS.Store for Meteor CollectionFS?

I'm looking to do some sort of function to do a check before each FS.Store and if it fails, just don't upload at all.

For example, I'm trying to check if the uploading image is a certain size. If it isn't, I'd like to stop proceeding with the upload for that FS.Store.

Answer (score 0):

CollectionFS is used to provide efficient way to upload from a file, an url, a blob etc on a storage such as data, GridFS, S3 etc…. The process of checking the data you will send to the server should be handled prior to uploading data to the Collection.

so as CollectionFS supports several kind of data, you might be able (or not) to filter the content before uploading them.

- File object (client only) // YES
- Blob object (client only) // YES
- Uint8Array // YES
- A data URI string // YES
- A full URL that begins with "http:" or "https:" // NO, not applicable
- A local filepath (server only) // NO (server only)
- ArrayBuffer Buffer (server only) // NO (server only)

The reason is very simple, into your template you can enum on the file you are willing to upload:

```
Template.myForm.events({
  'change .myFileInput': function(event, template) {
    FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
      // Test here what you want to test on "file", return if the test failed
      Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
      });
    });
  }
});
```

If you are uploading from an URL, you obviously cannot check the content before you download the content…. If you are uploading a file, blob, data URL string, Uint8Array, the data being still on the client side, it's your job to analyse it and grant or deny the upload.